# Can I save the state of the view when it is touched?

Tags: android, view, touch

I want to save the state of a view when it is touched. For example when I touch a view and after that I touched the another view in an activity I should be able to change the color of both the textviews at once. For this I need to save the state of the view which is touched at first. Is it possible?

Comment: you don't need to save state to do that. you can set a flag when a view is touched and when you can check that flag when another view is touched. Then you can call the setTextColor(). I'd request you to add more details to your query.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean "save state"? For your purpose you need save only id of first view and get it later by calling `findViewById(savedId)`.